# SQL Insert into based on an existing table and custom values

Tags: sql-server

I have tableA and tableB. TableA has a FK from tableBs PK. I want to create 11 new rows in tableA (0.0-1.0) with a new PK in tableA (it is on autoincrement) but with the selected FK from tableB that is gotten from the where for **each** FK but with their own identity in tableA. A total of 55 new rows in tableA (5x11 or type x value). So that the inserted rows look like

- tableAPK, tableBFK (type1), Order, 0.0
- tableAPK, tableBFK (type1), Order, 0.1
- tableAPK, tableBFK (type1), Order, 0.2 ...
- tableAPK, tableBFK (type2), Order, 0.0
- tableAPK, tableBFK (type1), Order, 0.1 ...

pseudocode

```
insert into [dbo].[tableA] ( [tableBFK],  [Order], [value])
    values ( (select [tableBPK], [Order]                                  
    from [dbo].[tableB]
    where [name] in('type1',
                    'type2',
                'type3',
                'type4',
                'type5'
                ),           
0,
0.1,
0.2,
0.3,
0.4,
0.5,
0.6,
0.7,
0.8,
0.9,
1)
```

Basically, I want to 1) select the PK of tableB based on certain conditions, 2) insert that PK along with some other of the tables values into tableA, 3) do this per tableBFK row (5) per hardcoded value (11) and map them together.
is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a temp table with the values you want, and doing a `CROSS JOIN` to it in your `INSERT`:

```
Declare @Values Table   (Value Decimal)
Insert  @Values Values  (0.0), (0.1), (0.2), (0.3), (0.4), (0.5), 
                        (0.6), (0.7), (0.8), (0.9), (1.0);

Insert      TableA
            (TableBFK, [Order], Value)
Select      B.TableBPK, B.[Order], V.Value
From        TableB  B
Cross Join  @Values V
Where       B.Name In ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4', 'Type5');
```

Comment: You can skip the declaration and just inline the table: `CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0.1), (0.2), (0.3), ...) B(Value)`